# Shell script command not running properly

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a shell script which will recursively find all list of files containing '*' text in it's body.

But on running the below command it gives me error

```
files.sh: line 6: _listOfDialog: command not found
```

Shell script code

```
_startDirectoryPath="/scratch/grep"
_listOfFiles="$(find . -type f -name '*.jsff')"

for file in $_listOfFiles
do
    _listOfDialog = $(tr '\n' ' ' < $file | grep -oP '(?<=<af:dialog).*?(?=     </af:dialog>)')
    echo  $_listOfDialog
done
```

I went through most of the post related to this but don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help me out

Comment: Paste your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ There are some obvious errors

Comment: Thank you @fedorqui. It helped

Comment: _listOfDialog=$(tr '\n' ' ' < $file | grep -oP '(?<=<af:dialog).*?(?=</af:dialog>)')